# Tensorflow: Computing gradients w.r.t. sub-tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let v be a Tensor. If I compute the gradient of another Tensor w.r.t to v everything works fine, i.e.

```
grads = tf.gradients(loss_func, v)
```

works fine.

However, when I want to compute the gradient w.r.t to just a single element or any subtensor of v, I get an error, i.e.

```
grads = tf.gradients(loss_func, v[0,0])
grads = tf.gradients(loss_func, v[:,1:])
```

produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/henning/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/henning/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "/Users/henning/pflow/testing.py", line 89, in <module>
    theta = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={P:P_inp, Q:Q_inp})
  File "/Users/henning/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/henning/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 952, in _run
    fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_string)
  File "/Users/henning/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 408, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/Users/henning/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 230, in for_fetch
    return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/Users/henning/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 337, in __init__
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/Users/henning/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 337, in <listcomp>
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/Users/henning/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 227, in for_fetch
    (fetch, type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to the problem.

The most elegant way of doing it that I found was to 'construct' v from constants and Variables and then compute the gradient w.r.t. the Variables, i.e.

```
v_free = tf.Variable(shape)
v_notfree = tf.constant(other_shape)
v = tf.concat([v_notfree, v_free])
loss_func = some function of v
grads = tf.gradients(loss_func, v_free)
```

Comment: May I ask you (unrelated to this topic) - does w.r.t. means with regards to? Because I came across with this shortcut for nth time considering machine learning topics and people here uses it a lot so I started wondering